# Cannot install any Feature/Role on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I was trying to install Exchange 2010 prerequisites, when I encountered some error. All look like the same. Like this one:
`Error: Installation of [Windows Process Activation Service] Configuration APIs failed. the server needs to be restarted to undo the changes.`
My server is running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition.
UPDATE: I tried installing the prerequisites one by one using PowerShell.
Now I have errors on RPC over Http proxy:

> Installation of [Web Server (IIS)]
>   Tracing Failed, Attempt to install
>   tracing failed with error code
>   0x80070643. Fatal error during
>   installation.

Searching about the error code doesn't tell me much more than something went wrong when trying to update windows. 
Installing Http Tracing alone also doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstall (all assuming this is an empty server, which it should be for exchange).

Comment: Well, this one can't be called troubleshooting, but would work for sure. Thanks for the answer anyway. I hope it wouldn't happen to me again in production.

Comment: It is waht I would to do start with. I mean, seriously - thanks to install from network that is a 5 minute wait ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try turning off UAC, rebooting & installing the pre-req's

Comment: No luck. That was the first thing I did.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with an IIS role service install.  I was logged in as a domain admin.  When I ran server manager "as administrator" it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've you've moved the system TEMP folders, try moving them back to the original C:\Windows\TEMP

I've seen that cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error also occurs when the server you are adding the feature to is using an IIS Shared Configuration setup.

In this case it is sufficient to remove the Shared Configuration, install the feature and then re-enable the Shared Configuration.